# What does ワソマソ mean?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to translate some of the signs in the anime FLCL, and I came across this sign on the side of a train in the first episode:

ワソマソ
出入口

The second part means "doorway", correct? But what about ワソマソ ? What does 'Wasomaso' mean? Or am I reading it wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 18):

This is probably `ワンマン` (note `ン` instead of `ソ`). `ワンマン` is wasei-eigo from "one man". For example, `ワンマンショー` (one man show), or `ワンマンライブ` (meaning a live performance with just one band, not necessarily one person).

In the context of buses, `ワンマン` means that a bus is being operated by a driver alone, with no conductor (i.e. every bus nowadays). It used to be a rule to have this sign if there was no conductor.

So this is not a phrase ("one man doorway"), but a two-purpose sign showing the doorway and stating that the bus is `ワンマン`.

Of course, this being FLCL it's possible that it actually **does** say `ワソマソ`, as a joke. A Google search reveals that it is sometimes used jokingly.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it wasn't [`ワンマン`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%83%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3/UTF-8/), a word which apparently would mean ["one-man operation/driver-only operation/one person operation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-man_operation) in this context? (in other contexts `ワンマン` can mean "dictator" or "autocrat".)

**Edit:** Fixed definition.

Comment: If it were ワンマン in this context, it would not mean what you wrote. It would mean a carriage with only one crew (only the driver, without a conductor).

Comment: Yes, cypher, that is what it says. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I have been on small trains (most recently: [Eizan railway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eizan_Electric_Railway) in Kyoto) that indeed bear messages along the line of 'ワンマン', followed by information on how/where to board/alight the train (the 出入口 part).

For example, Eiden asks passengers to exit through the front door, due to the train being 'ワンマン'.

Eiden translates `ワンマン` as `conductorless` (a somewhat ungrammatical but easily understandable word). In absence of a conductor, the train still usually has one person driving and/or attending to the doors and tickets.

Although all the other meanings mentioned in this thread are valid translations of this term, given context, I think "conductorless" (or equivalent) is the most likely one.

Comment: I thought Eiden has a driver on it, and the driver comes to the door and do the tickets. Doesn't it? If it is indeed (wo)man-less, it would be called 無人.

Comment: @sawa: as I said: it definitely does have a person on board, that does tickets and gates. I honestly couldn't tell you if they are really driving it (I have a strong suspicion that it is mostly automated, but the person might have the possibility to take over if needed).

Comment: Then, I don't understand why you claim it should be zero rather than one. The total number of crews is one, not zero.

Comment: @sawa: I meant to say that conductorless could have implied nobody aboard, but nevermind. I edited my answer to make it clearer.